# DB2: Unable to set 'Default' value

Tags: sql, db2

I am new to `DB2`. So please bear with me. Below is the query being used to fetch the data. The intention is to set "Default" value if nothing is found:

Query:

```
SELECT t1.col1,t1.col2,t1.col3,t1.col4,t1.col5 FROM TABLE t1 FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

What I tried:

```
SELECT t1.col1,t1.col2,t1.col3,t1.col4 SET DEFAULT 'Data Missing',t1.col5 FROM TABLE t1 FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;

SELECT t1.col1,t1.col2,t1.col3,COALESCE(t1.col4 SET,'Data Missing'),t1.col5 FROM TABLE t1 FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;

SELECT t1.col1,t1.col2,t1.col3,COALESCE(t1.col4 SET,0),t1.col5 FROM TABLE t1 FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;

SELECT t1.col1,t1.col2,t1.col3,t1.col4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Data Missing',t1.col5 FROM TABLE t1 FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

But, none of these is working.

In MySQL, I can achieve the same by:

```
SELECT t1.col1,t1.col2,t1.col3,t1.col4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Data Missing', t1.col5 FROM TABLE t1 LIMIT 5;
```

Update_1:Tried below

```
select col1,
case
when col4 is null then 'Data Missing' else col4 end as col4
when col3 is null then 'Data Missing' else col3 end as col3
when col2 is null then 'Data Missing' else col2 end as col2
from my_table
fetch first 5 rows only;
```

Error:

```
1) [Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  An unexpected token "WHEN" was found following "END AS COL4
".  Expected tokens may include:  "INTO".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.22.29

2) [Code: -727, SQL State: 56098]  An error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-104", SQLSTATE "42601" and message tokens "WHEN|END AS COL4
```

Comment: To which column? Each one of them?

Comment: @TheImpaler. Trying to set the 'Default' value for 't1.col4'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming col4 is of a char type:

```
select
    col1, col2, col3, coalesce(col4, 'Data Missing') as col4
  from my_table
  fetch first 5 rows only
```

A more generic solution to massage data could be:

```
select
    col1, col2, col3,
    case
      when col4 is null then 'Data Missing'
      -- you can add more "when" cases here.
      else col4
    end as col4
  from my_table
  fetch first 5 rows only
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't add comments yet.. as to Your "Update_1", You have forgotten to separate columns with commas (and repeat the CASE word), so it should read:

```
select col1,
case when col4 is null then 'Data Missing' else col4 end as col4,
case when col3 is null then 'Data Missing' else col3 end as col3,
case when col2 is null then 'Data Missing' else col2 end as col2
from my_table
fetch first 5 rows only;
```

Or simply

```
select col1,
COALESCE(col4, 'Data Missing') as col4,
COALESCE(col3, 'Data Missing') as col3,
COALESCE(col2, 'Data Missing') as col2
from my_table
fetch first 5 rows only;
```